# IE times-out after 5 min

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, http, networking, httpresponse

We have a web application which does some computing and returns a file to the client. When the computing takes less then 5 minutes everything works fine on IE and Chrome and we get the file but if computing takes more than 5 minutes IE times-out with "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" message where as Chrome keeps running and eventually gets the file from the server.

I've tried changing registry settings like KeepAliveTimeout, ReceiveTimeout, ServerInfoTimeout  of WinInet but it didn't help. Clicking the Diagnose Connection Problems button shows "Windows received an HTTPerror message: 403 (forbidden) from " message which I think is because it tries to again access the site without credentials and fails. When using fiddler the request terminates with 504 status and show this message "ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request." Interestingly I've once observed that even Chrome times-out if Fiddler is running (haven't verified this by re-running though.)

This is an ASP.Net web application using MVC framework.

I've spent considerable amount of time but haven't been able to find a solution for this. Any useful pointers would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From [KB181050](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181050)

> You can usually break down long processes into smaller pieces. Or, the server can return status data to update users about the process. In addition, you can create a long server process that has a messages-based or asynchronous approach so that it returns immediately to the user after the job is submitted, and then notifies the user after the long process is finished.

In other words, create a `<div>` and fill that `<div>` immediately with a "processing" value after the request has been accepted by the server.  Then, use ajax or javascript to update that same `<div>` with the result whenever you're finished with processing.